# Checking if node is connected to specific plug using Maya API

Tags: c++, maya

Suppose I have two connected nodes in Maya (a material and its Shading Group node). Using Maya API, how can I find out if the SG node which is an **MObject** is connected to outColor of the material?

Answer (score 2):

You can take look in this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gpalem/2008/08/20/how-to-find-the-shading-groups-for-a-shape-node-in-maya-api/) , you can use findPlug and connectedTo to get what you looking for.